# Finding Periodicity from Data Separated by New Lines using Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling with all the steps needed to get some data tracking a particular symptom from my graphics calculator to the point where I may be able so find some periodicity and thereby infer potential causal relationships. Unfortunately, one of the symptoms is brain fog...

I've managed to get the data from the calculator into "supposed csv file", although it doesn't look like one. It is formatted like so, from the software which did the conversion:

```
0.25
0.5
1
2
2.5
2
1.5
1.5
...
...
...
```

I was hoping something nice and simple like

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("L5.csv")
print(df.shape)

print(pd.infer_freq(df))
```

Might do the trick, but I get

```
(356, 1)
None
```

I can't even tell at this point if the shape means I've got a 1D list to work with. And if I have, is something like `print(pd.infer_freq(df))` going to give me what I need?

Any help much appreciated.

EDIT the full data is shown below:

```
0.25
0.5
1
2
2.5
2
1.5
1.5
2
2
2.5
2
2
2.5
2.5
2
2.5
2
2
2.5
2.5
2.5
2.5
2.5
1.75
3.25
2
2
2
2
2.5
2
3
2.5
2
2
1.5
1.5
2.25
3
2.5
2.75
2.5
1.5
2
2.5
2.25
1.75
3
2.25
2.5
2.75
2
2.25
2.25
3
2.25
2.25
1.25
1.5
1.25
2
2
2.5
2.5
2.25
1.25
1.5
2
2
2.25
3
2.75
2.25
2
2
1.75
1.75
1.75
2.5
2.5
2.5
2
2.75
2.75
2
2.5
3
2.5
2.75
2.75
3
2.5
3
2.75
2.75
2.5
2.5
2.25
2.25
2.5
2.75
2.5
2.5
2.5
2.5
3
2.5
2.25
2
3
2.75
3.25
2.5
2.75
3
3.25
2.5
2.5
2.75
2.75
2.75
2.5
3.25
3.5
2.75
4
3.75
2.5
3
2.25
2.25
1.75
1.5
1.5
1.75
1.5
3.5
2.5
3
2.75
2.75
2
1.5
1.25
2.25
2.5
2.75
3.5
3.25
2.25
2.75
2.75
3
2.75
2.5
3.25
2
1
1.5
2.5
3
2.75
3
3
3.25
2.75
2.75
3
2.75
2.25
3
2.5
2.5
2
1.75
2
1.25
1.5
2.5
2.75
3.5
3
2.75
3
3.25
3
3.25
3.25
3
2.75
2.75
2.75
3.25
2.5
2.5
2
1.5
2
2.25
3
3.25
2.75
2
1.75
1.5
2.25
3
2.25
2.75
2.75
3.5
2.75
2.75
2
2
1.5
2.75
2.5
3.5
3
2.25
1.5
1.75
1.75
1.75
2
2.25
2.75
3.25
2.5
3.5
2.5
3.25
3
2.5
2.5
2.75
3.25
2.5
2
2.75
3
2.75
3
2.25
3.25
2
2
2.75
2.75
2.5
3
3.25
3
3.5
3.25
2.75
2.75
2.75
2.25
3.25
3.25
2.25
2
1.75
2.25
2.5
2.75
2
2.75
3
3.5
3.25
3.5
3
3.25
2.5
3
3.25
2.5
2.5
2.75
2.75
3.25
2.5
2
3
2.25
3
3.75
3.5
3
2.25
1.75
2
1.75
2.25
3
2.5
1.5
1.5
1.75
2
3
3
2.25
2.5
2
2.5
3.25
2
2.5
3
2.75
3.25
3
3
3
2
2.25
2.75
3.25
2.75
3
2.25
2.5
2.25
1.5
1.5
2
1.5
1.75
1.5
2.5
2.5
3
2.75
3.25
3.25
3.25
2.5
2
2.75
3
1.75
3
1.75
2
2.5
1.5
2.5
3.25
2.5
3.25
3.25
3
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole dataset and explain which kind of periodicity you would expect? (365 = daily data for a year?)

Comment: @mozway It would be a bit long winded to provide the whole set. It's basically almost exactly a years worth of daily scores from 0-5. I'm hoping that maybe some kind of pattern might emerge, like "approximately every 5 days there is a slump", or "there seems to be a roughly weekly cycle," which I might then be able relate to anything in my lifestyle with a similar period, such as diet, exertion, etc.

Comment: It's just that it would be easier to test on the real data, rather than random of crafted ;)

Comment: @mozway OK great. I've edited the question to include the full data set.

Comment: Thanks, I tested an autocorrelation but there is little obvious correlation: `pd.plotting.autocorrelation_plot(df['col'])` / https://i.stack.imgur.com/bw15k.png  You can compare to random shuffling: `pd.plotting.autocorrelation_plot(df['col'].sample(frac=1))`

Comment: @Thanks. I'm not quite sure what you've done there as I'm not a data scientist, but I'm guessing that means no obvious cycles or outstanding features - basically random, as I've kind of suspected...?

Comment: autocorrelation means that you compare the time series with a shifted version or itself, if there is a correlation at lag X you know there is a X periodicity. Check the [`pandas.plotting.autocorrelation_plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.plotting.autocorrelation_plot.html) for an example of periodic data. Here I used the shuffled series as control to have an uncorrelated example